# Xamarin.Forms - Bind Multiple Button Clicks Within Listview Cell?

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display a list of items, each containing several buttons and other tappable elements. The problem is, by default, each item in a Listview is tappable. How do I disable that, and bind tappable events to elements inside a Listview?

Comment: As far as I know, the listview will only react to taps that are not on elements inside the cells that handle the tap themselves. At least that's how I implemented something like that.

Comment: like multi select?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a custom view cell:

```
public class MyCell : ViewCell
{
    public MyCell ()
    {
        var button1 = new Button {Text = "Button 1"};
        button1.Clicked += (sender1, e1) => {
           // Action for button 1
        };
        var button2 = new Button {Text = "Button 2"};
        button2.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
          // Action for Button 2
        };
        View = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = {
                 button1,
                 button2,
            }
        };
        View.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer());
    }
}
```

The last TapGestureRecognizer is to avoid selection (and on android displaying) of the touch.

And integrate this in your ListView

```
public DemoPage ()
{
    var listView = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = new[] {"cell 1", "cell 2", "cell 3", "cell 4"},
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof (MyCell))
    };
    Content = listView;
}
```

You also can bind the button clicks to commands

Answer (score 0):

If you're using actual Button elements, you shouldn't have to do anything special.  Each Button will respond to it's own Clicked event.  The row's Tapped event should only fire for regions outside of the button elements.